# Why does my R session keep getting interrupted? It says fatal error

Tags: r, memory, package, fatal-error, crash-reports

I am currently running some analysis in R relating to the AGH package.  My R session keeps getting interrupted. It says fatal error and asks me to start a new session. Could this be a memory issue? How do I solve this issue?

Comment: please share your code and some data so we can help further

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mabel! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: In this situation, some things that will help: before you get to the point of "crash", [edit] your question here and paste the output of `sessionInfo()` into a [code block]. Also, realize that we know nothing about your data, your process, the arguments/parameters you're using for your analysis, etc. Also, I don't know what the `AGH` package is, and cannot find it on CRAN. Where is it?

Comment: The AGH package is a non-base package used to estimate genomic relatedness between animals of a population. I realised that the crashing wasn't specific to a particular script that I wrote at the time but to other scripts as well.